# How to Locate an android mobile in web

Tags: android

I created one android application which will be used by multiple users, so I want to track the user's of my application using a web browser kind of application.

I Know about Android Device Manager which will track the mobile phone of  google account. In this case i have to restrict my all user's to use same gmail account so that i can track all of them, But i don't want to restrict users to use same gmail for their personal mobile phone.

I am thinking is there any way by coding we can locate/mark the device on the google map of one particular account. say i have 10 user's my code has to locate/mark all these 10 users to Map of gmail account say xxx@gmail.com. is this possible ?

How to achieve this requirement? Need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,

1. You can ask users for location access rights and than keep tracking their location data (i.e. latitude and longitude values).
2. Once you have latitude and longitude values of all the users putting them in a google map will be a straight forward task using Google Maps API.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks Amit.I'm fetching longitude and latitude value from the application and at regular intervals i am sending the same to the server. So at the server side we can you the latitude and longitude to get the location of the user!

Comment: Latitude and longitude are basically representing the location of the user..

Comment: Yes,I had bit confusion of getting the values in offline mode. But now it is clear